# Routes with a wrong format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with Nodejs and I am trying to figure out why my routes are getting a wrong format, look at this example

I have a service named `Dealers`, and these are the routes

```
import express from 'express';

const router = new express.Router();
// POST METHODS
router.post('/create-dealer', require('./create-dealer'));
router.post('/update-dealer', require('./update-dealer'));
router.post('/deactive-dealer', require('./deactive-dealer'));

// GET METHODS
router.get('/get-dealers', require('./get-dealers'));

export default router;
```

and the general `app.use`

```
import { Router } from 'express';
const router = new Router();

router.use('/create-dealer', require('./dealers'));
router.use('/get-dealers', require('./dealers'));
router.use('/update-dealer', require('./dealers'));
router.use('/deactive-dealer', require('./dealers'));

export default router;
```

now, in order for me to work with this routes, I have to do for example in Postman

> **POST > http://localhost:8080/create-dealer/create-dealer**

and why not only

> **POST > http://localhost:8080/create-dealer**

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `app.js` it should be:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
const router = new Router();

router.use(require('./dealers'));

export default router;
```

Because you already have the paths specified in `dealers.js`.

Answer (score 2):

You're inserting that `create-dealer` segment twice by having it both in the `.use` file and again in the `'./dealers'` file.

Either eliminate it where you use it:

```
router.use('/create-dealer', require('./dealers'));
```

to

```
router.use('/', require('./dealers'));
```

...which may mean you have to refactor `'./dealers'` or you'll need to do the reverse, leave it with `router.use` and remove it in the `dealers` code.

Comment: Just a quick note, `router.use(require('./dealers'));` is shorthand for `router.use('/', require('./dealers'));`